# 'androidx.emoji2:emoji2:1.4.0' requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the Android APIs

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, gradle-kotlin-dsl

The project stopped building after importing `import androidx.compose.ui.draw.alpha`
SDK everywhere 33, it shows a dependency conflict

Error log:

```
An issue was found when checking AAR metadata:

  1.  Dependency 'androidx.emoji2:emoji2:1.4.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-33.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 34, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).
```

My dependencies:

```
dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))

    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")

    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.2")
    implementation("androidx.wear.compose:compose-material:1.2.0")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
}
```

I tried to change the version (1.4.0 and 1.3.0)

```
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.4.0")
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics:1.4.0")
```

but it didn't work

Comment: So did you update your `compileSdk` to 34 like the error message says?

Comment: @ ianhanniballake 
No, the project does not currently require support for API 34 (Android 14)

Comment: Changing the `compileSdk` value does not imply "support for API 34". It simply changes what version of the Android SDK that your module compiles against.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try updating the `compileSdk` in the `app` module's `build.gradle` to 34.

The app's behavior won't change until you upgrade the `targetSdk` (and, as the description of the error says, you don't have to do it right now)

Comment: I feel that doing that doesn't really solve the problem. The solution should come with an explanation of why the bug occurs and how to avoid it by maintaining your settings.

Comment: @ErnestoDavidOlivaPerez It's a compile-time error with a message including '*Dependency ... requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the Android APIs.*'. To resolve it, you need to ensure that the `compileSdk` of the depending module (*app*) is set to at least 34, matching the dependency.

Comment: I don't agree with you. On this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/295457468) some people have my same idea that updating SDK is not a solution, read comment number 4.

Comment: @ErnestoDavidOlivaPerez I wouldn't call it that. In general, it's a basic, pretty cheap, and safe solution for cases like this; developers do have to do it from time to time. Maybe in this specific case, there are also some other solutions that work as well

Answer (score -1):

Take a close look at the version of the dependent Compose Material library
**For API 33 use version 1.1.2**

Replace `implementation("androidx.wear.compose:compose-material:1.2.0")`
to `implementation("androidx.wear.compose:compose-material:1.1.2")`

Comment: This solution means that bug fixes in 1.2.0 (or newer versions) of the library will not be available to you.